# Error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to do a HttpWebRequest(POST) to send some data to a server. However I always got error: (403) Forbidden. This is my current code:

```
foreach (Patient patient in patients)
                {

                    string[] names = patient.Nome.Split(' ');
                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8090/ehr/rest/createPerson");
                    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiZXh0cmFkYXRhIjp7Im9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiI6IjY2NjYifSwiaXNzdWVkX2F0IjoiMjAxNi0wNC0yMlQxMzo0ODoyOS40ODRaIn0=.Fztrd8LR/FkBY2CJLjnl/qYYYjz1/vr4g01e8yTad/0=");
                    request.Accept = "application/json";

                    string tempUrl = "firstName=" + names[0];
                    tempUrl += "&lastName=" + names[names.Length - 1];
                    tempUrl += "&dob=" + patient.Data_Nasc;
                    tempUrl += "&role=pat";
                    tempUrl += "&sex=" + "M";
                    tempUrl += "&organizationUid=" + organization.Uid;
                    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tempUrl);

                    request.Method = "POST";
                    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

                    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                        stream.Close();
                    }
                    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                }
```

I know that there is a lot of questions about this error, but no answer resolve my problem. Im still getting error 403.
Next is the stacktrace:

```
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at IndexDocClinicos.Classes.EhrData.createPersons() in c:\Users\Joaogcorreia\Desktop\EHR + Solr + IndexDocClinicos\Indexacao-de-Documentos-Clinicos\Indexação de Documentos Clinicos\IndexDocClinicos\Classes\EhrData.cs:line 163
   at IndexDocClinicos.WebApiApplication.Application_Start() in c:\Users\Joaogcorreia\Desktop\EHR + Solr + IndexDocClinicos\Indexacao-de-Documentos-Clinicos\Indexação de Documentos Clinicos\IndexDocClinicos\Global.asax.cs:line 37
```

I already tried this POST with Insomnia and it works very well. So I have no ideia what is wrong. I also verified and the token is correct.

pls help

thanks =)

Comment: Some servers to prevent hacker from figuring out how to get into a server by using the error message put out none standard errors.  The best way of debugging http connection is using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Then compare http headers using an IE with c# application.  Make sure you clear IE history between tries because the cookies effect both the IE results and the c# application.

Comment: If I were you I'd check your token again, and make sure it allows you to make the request you're trying to make - just because it works for one request doesn't necessarily mean it'll work for a different request. The token will likely expire after a certain time period too. A 403 means you aren't authorised to perform a request, without knowing more about the service you're POSTing to it's hard to give you a more definite answer than this. There's nothing obviously wrong with the code you've provided.